# Android suddenly freed up several GB of space itself? (Note 3)

Tags: internal-storage, ram, samsung-galaxy-note-3

My Note3 has been nearly full (~500MB or so left) for a month or so.

Tonight I was web-browsing in Chrome, and accidentally hit "download" on a gigantic multi-GB file on archive.org.  Chrome froze up for a while (maybe 10-30 seconds or so).  I scrambled to get to Settings to turn off mobile data, and luckily the download failed.

Here's the really weird thing.  When I started poking around the phone afterwards, I was really surprised to see over 3GB of memory free.  There had been probably less than 700MB free before this happened.

Where did all that space come from?

On the face of it this would seem to be great-- "yay, free space!".  But, I am a little antsy and confused, as well as just plain curious, because I have no idea how the phone did this.

1) Is this a known behavior that Android does sometimes?  I don't recall ever seeing this happen before.  I vaguely remember Windows having some laundry list of things it deletes when space needs are dire-- does Android do something similar?  Maybe some kind of backup installer / system snapshot / crash dump kinds of files?

2) Is there any way of finding out what it deleted?  Or otherwise what it did to get this space clear?

(I'm hoping to find out what it did delete, b/c I want to make sure it didn't just choose to delete something I wanted to keep, ie "hey, you haven't looked at these photos in three months, so you'll never miss them; they're going in the trash.")

3) If it deleted some backup install or system snapshot or crash dump kinds of files, that'd be great... but it'd also be great how to TELL it to delete these kinds of things next time to free up the space by choice.  In other words, "If I could have had 3GB this easily all along, how can I ask for it?"

Comment: I heard that iOS has such a feature (there was a report a while back that by downloading a huge file a cleanup process was triggered, most likely removing caches and temporary stuff, to free up space). Never heard of such a thing on Android, though. What Android version do you have running on the device?

Comment: My phone is Android 5.0, Note3, Verizon.

Comment: Now that you mention versions, it wasn't that long ago (a few to 6 months) that the phone updated itself to 5.0. Maybe there were installer files or something that it deleted?

Comment: There was such a thing in the past (around 4.2), when internal storage was "remapped". On some devices, files had then been copied over to the new place, but were also left in the old (without the user having an easy way to access that old space). But even then, downloading a "big file" didn't trigger a cleanup, the user had to do that manually. If the ring buffer was big enough, you might find some traces in `adb logcat` – but I'm afraid it's too late for that now (those entries most likely have been rotated out already).

Comment: BTW, I backed up all my personal data from the phone last night. (Pictures, office docs, ebooks, etc.)  I compared to my previous backup and didn't see any unexpected difference. So whatever the phone cleared, it doesn't appear to have been personal data.

Comment: On the logcat cmd, I read about that somewhere, but I thought I'd have to be rooted to do it (I'm not). I should try that. Thanks!

Comment: `adb logcat` doesn't require root. Most ADB commands can be used without the device being rooted. Be welcome to our [ADB tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info) :)